# how to read 12 digit numeric in sas

Tags: sas

i am new to sas trying to read csv file

sample of csv i am trying to read

Olive Mathews , 119-574-8639 , 47 Summit Ave , 22186,Portugal

Jami Gonzales , 182-680-4169 , 81521 Chico Hwy , 69148 , Cambodia

Mabel Holland , 561-729-2640 , 87 State Hwy 160 , 32798 , Viet Nam

Alice Barron , 453-687-5745 , 621 State Hwy 171 N , 41322 , Belize

sas code i wrote to read csv

```
data jul10.second;

infile '/folders/myshortcuts/myfolder/csv/data.csv' dlm=',' firstobs=2  ;
length name$20 phoneno 7 address$40 zipcode 6 country$40 ;
input name$ phoneno address $ zipcode  country$;
 run;
```

gives error at phoneno variable  (Invalid data for phoneno in line 2 15-26.)

but if i convert phoneno variable into character variable there is no error -

```
 data jul10.second;

infile '/folders/myshortcuts/myfolder/csv/data.csv' dlm=',' firstobs=2  ;
length name$20 phoneno $12 address$40 zipcode 6 country$40 ;
input name$ phoneno $ address $ zipcode  country$;
 run;
```

why is that ? why i cant put 12digit number in numeric variable phoneno ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 12-digit 'number' isn't a number due to the hyphens. If you wish to convert it to a number without the hyphens, use the `compress()` function to remove them, and `input()` to convert to a number...

```
realphone = input(compress(phoneno,'-'),10.) ;
```

Comment: And why would you need this variable to be a 'number' anyway? If it is a phone number, I don't imagine you would be using it in calculations.

Comment: i dont know professor said never take phoneno as char you might end up doing statistical analysis on them one day though i dont know how is that possible

Comment: Phone numbers should *never* be taken as numeric.  You're not going to do math on them, and any statistical analysis you would do would be character-oriented (first 3 chars=area code, second 3 chars=exchange) which do not have numeric relationships (212 is not 'smaller' than 312, nor is 212-213-312 in any sort of relationship where larger/smaller is relevant).  The same argument holds true for zip codes.  In general, identifying variables should be character unless they are sequential IDs.